# Duplicate files with similar file names in UNIX

Tags: unix, sed

I have a set of files in a single directory named:

```
OneThing-x.extension
OneThing-y.extension
OneThing-z.extension
```

What UNIX command (find, cp, xargs, sed ?) do I use to COPY these into

```
AnotherThing-x.extension
AnotherThing-y.extension
AnotherThing-z.extension
```

such that x ->copy-> x, and y ->copy -> y

I have the find .. part of the command to start with,which selects the files, but I am stuck there.

**EDIT**
Obviously, I want to keep both the original and the copy, so a rename does not quite do the trick for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
$ touch a1.a a2.a a3.a
$ ls

a1.a  a2.a  a3.a

$ for a in a*.a ; do cp $a $(echo $a | sed 's/^a/b/') ; done
$ ls

a1.a  a2.a  a3.a  b1.a  b2.a  b3.a
```

Comment: The shortest and most elegant solution offered. And, it worked like a charm!

Comment: A regular cantrip in my toolbox (though I'm old enough to default to backticks). Sometimes with a find to get the input list. The thing to watch out for is uniqueness in the replacement regexp. Safest to use run it with echo instead of cp the first time.

Comment: Quote your shell variables, in case you ever use such scripts with  filenames (or directory names) that contain spaces. (We won't talk about filenames that start with a '-', cos they're just evil.)

Comment: Real Unix users don't create filenames with spaces or upper case letters(!). But yes, if that's a risk then the variables should be quoted. And, as dmckee suggests, running with echo first is a really good idea. That's exactly how I do it.

Answer (score 1):

My rough solution would be something like:

```
for FIL in OneThing*; do NFIL=`echo $FIL|sed 's/OneThing/AnotherThing/'`; cp "$FIL" "$NFIL"; done;
```

Answer (score 1):

Extending [Jason Musgrove's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078691/duplicate-files-with-similar-file-names-in-unix/1078712#1078712):

```
for FIL in OneThing*
do
  NFIL=`echo $FIL | sed 's/OneThing/AnotherThing/'`
  cp "$FIL" "$NFIL"
done
```

Comment: Douglas: Oops, yes - I missed out piping echo $FIL into sed. Good catch.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ rename 's/OneThing/AnotherThing/' *.extension
```

Comment: Given that the original question asked for a copy, this may not actually produce the required result

Answer (score 0):

You could also use mmv:

```
$ mmv -c "OneThing*" "AnotherThing#1"
```

or

```
$ mmv -c "OneThing-*.extension" "AnotherThing-#1.extension"
```

Comment: "apt-get install mmv" will solve this if you are using a debian based distribution. I'm sure the RPM bases distributions provide a similar package.